# Use Imagemagick to find areas of similar colour

Tags: python, image, colors, imagemagick, pixel

Is there any way to use ImageMagick (or something similar, anything that will work!) to find areas of an image where the pixels beside each other are a similar color?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the context of the question?  You can certainly use an image processing application (Gimp, PS, etc) to select a pixel with the mouse and extend the selection to contiguous areas of similar color.  But in the context of an application, what do you expect to be returned to the caller after a function "finds areas of an image"?

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop, Gimp and Plenty of other image processors will do this for you. Programmatically, here is some code in python that accomplishes this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

def inImage(im, px):
    x,y = px
    return x < im.size[0] and y < im.size[1] and x > 0 and y > 0

def meetsThreshold(im, px, st, threshold):
    color = im.getpixel(px)
    similar = im.getpixel(st)
    for cPortion, sPortion in zip(color,similar):
        if abs(cPortion - sPortion) > threshold:
            return False
    return True

def floodFill(im, fillaroundme, fillWith, meetsThresholdFunction):
    imflooded = im.copy()
    imflooded.putpixel(fillaroundme, fillwith)
    processed = []
    toProcess = [fillaroundme]
    while len(toProcess) > 0:
        edge = toProcess.pop()
        processed.append(edge)
        x, y = edge
        for checkMe in ((x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)):
            if inImage(im, checkMe) and meetsThresholdFunction(im, edge, checkMe):
                imflooded.putpixel(checkMe, fillWith)            
                if checkMe not in toProcess and checkMe not in processed:
                    toProcess.append(checkMe)
        processed.append(edge)
    return imflooded


im = Image.open(r"tardis.jpg")
filled = floodFill(im, (120, 220), (255, 0, 0), lambda im, px, st: meetsThreshold(im, px, st, 10))

filled.show()
```

I got the tardis.jpg from [here](http://hrminion.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/817176-tardis.jpg)